# recommendation on studying real-analysis

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

I hope someone who had studied RCA would answer my question.

I bought Rudin-Real and Complex analysis for self-study.
(Please don't mind that it is a self-study. I don't care at all whether a text is extremely terse or student-friendly.)

I really liked Rudin's style when i studied PMA, but I think the first two chapters of RCA are not good. In the index of the book, he wrote "First 7 chapters of Principles of Analysis-Rudin are enough to start this book". But after i studied first two chapters of RCA, i realized it requires more than that.

And I felt like he's trying to put *too much* information on each page.

He proves the existence of "Lebesgue Measure" in a single theorem through Riesz-Markov Representation, not introducing outer measure nor Caratheodory theorem.

This approach is maybe good to save pages, but it's not good at all to understand properties. It really doesn't matter to me whether a text is hard or not. However, when a text doesn't introduce something one must highly know, it is a problem. (It would be really hard to check properties of the Lebesgue measure through a representation and then through a limit)

So I read the first chapter "Measure" of Folland's analysis text in library and it introduces "Measure space and Constructing a measure space" in more details. I liked it, so i will go through next two chapters more.

My questions is "On which chapter of Folland, should i go back to RCA"?

I don't have time for studying both texts, and I want to study RCA rathen than Folland's text if i have to choose one.

Comment: I am self-studying Rudin's real complex analysis now. Personally, I liked the approach of defining the Lebesgue measure through the Reisz representation theorem more than the other one.

Comment: There are many approaches to the Lebesgue measure. A more elementary approach is in Rudin's PMA, for example. The approach in RCA is more abstract, but the whole book carries a higher level of exposition than PMA, so that's to be expected. Another approach is through outer measures, as you say. Different books are going to follow different presentations, and it is not a matter of saving pages. The same is true with complex analysis, there are many different ways of presenting the theory, and different texts are going to follow wildly different paths which, of course, end up being equivalent.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo "and different texts are going to follow wildly different paths which, of course, end up being equivalent." An apt description for complex analysis ;)

Comment: @Andres Caicedo Rudin does not end up being equivalent. He never introduces an outer measure until the end of the page. And Yes, I expected it to be harder than PMA. But as I said, i don't want to loose accuracy. Have you read the proof for the existence of Lebesgue measure in RCA? It's unbelievably short and does not give enough information.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with Rudin's presentation, or else I would not have commented on this. You are not losing (one "o") accuracy at all. In any case, this is really a matter or taste, so I will not comment further here.